# Text Wrapping Jumping when <span> is Pinned

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking for a css or javascript solution to this problem. I am using ScrollMagic to pin some text to the browser window as here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJrZJx

The problem is that the span to the right jumps around when the pinned text is pinned and un-pinned. I am trying to get the span to the right (`#right-span`) of the pinned text to stay in place when the pinned text is pinned/unpinned.

Here is an image describing the intended behavior:

[image]

Any idea as to how to keep the span to the right in its original position?

---

HTML:

```
<span id="name-font" style="font-weight: 800; color:red;">PIN THIS TEXT BUT KEEP THE SPACING OF THE TEXT IN THIS RIGHT SPAN --></span>
<span id="right-span"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam finibus nisi nisl, etc. </span>
```

JS:

```
        var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
        var sceneNameFont = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: "#name-font",
            triggerHook: 0
        })
        .setPin("#name-font")
        .setVelocity("#name-font", {color: '#0000FF'}, {duration: 500})
        .addTo(controller);
```

Comment: You are taking the pinned text in and out of the dom flow when you pin and un-pin it.  If you don't want the other text to jump, then you need to position those independently from the span you are trying to pin.

Comment: Thanks @SeanStopnik yeh I get that. But is there a way to get a natural word-wrap if I use different positioning?